# Get data from mysql to edit on CKEditor

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, ckeditor

i got stuck because i can not display data on database MySql to CKEditor (textarea).

its work for `<input>` tag. but not work for `<textare>` tag because have plugin CKEditor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#editmodal", function () {
     var idArt = $(this).data('id');
     var contentArt = $(this).data('isi'); //CKeditor

     $("#Eid").val(idArt);
     $("#Econtent").val(contentArt); //CKeditor
     CKeditor.replace("Econtent");

});
</script>
```

i just want to edit/update data. thank you before.

HTML :

```
            <form action="proses_edit_post.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12"><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> ID POST : </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Eid" name="Eid" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Content Artikel : </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="Econtent" name="Econtent" placeholder="Keterangan Boleh kosong !" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
            </form>
```

And this is i call the data with modal :

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' 
data-toggle='modal'
data-id='$row[id_art]'
data-isi='$row[isi_art]'
data-target='#myEdit' 
contenteditable='false' 
id='editmodal'>
</button>
```

Comment: show your html too

Comment: when store into db use  html_entity_encode($result['EMAIL_BODY']) and when show decode and show like this <textarea name="email_body" required="required"><?php echo   html_entity_decode($result['EMAIL_BODY']) ?></textarea>

Comment: textarea don't value attribute you need to do like this $("#content").text(contentArt);  or $("#content").html(contentArt);

Comment: try my below answer @Dragon Chs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First of all your not echoing data properly .inside the single quotes everything consider as string . you need to echo it properly

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' 
data-toggle='modal'
data-id='<?php echo $row[id_art]; ?>'
data-isi='<?php echo $row[isi_art]; ?>'
data-target='#myEdit' 
contenteditable='false' 
id='editmodal'>
```

2) your textarea ID is **Econtent**   but your using id name as  **content**

```
   $("#content").val(contentArt);
```

change to

Textarea don't have value attribute but you can able to set content to texarea using val() so do like this

```
   $("#Econtent").val(contentArt);
```

OR

```
   `$("#Econtent").html(contentArt);`
```

OR

```
    `$("#Econtent").text(contentArt);`
```

Comment: add echo not working because im on php page. field idArt is show, but textarea still not showing.

Comment: still not work sir.
maybe there is something wrong in here ?
`<script>CKEDITOR.replace('Eisi');</script>`

Comment: all good.. can u check this script `<script>CKEDITOR.replace('Econtent');</script>` ? maybe need to add something

Comment: sir.. its work when i add `CKeditor.replace("Econtent")` above `$("#Econtent").html(contentArt);`. but data textarea always display same data. example i open id 1, then i open id 2. data textarea will display id 1. but if im not use CKeditor. its work fine.

Comment: its  work now. i have create html textarea on jquery.. :D